# 0x80070643 Error installing Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 Windows Server Hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to install the hosting package on a test server running Windows Server 2008 R2, and I get `Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.` in the logs. I was running the command `DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting.exe OPT_INSTALL_REDIST=0` in order to only install the ASP.NET Core module for IIS. I also tried running the full install, with the same result.

I've seen errors regarding tooling, but this is an entirely different installer.